# On capture Image rotate

Tags: java, android

After taking image from camera in Moto devices when image set it gets to rotated left  90 degrees.
I already googled  used ExifInterface  but not solved.

Comment: show what you tried, and why it didn't work. If you wont do that, your question likely will be closed as a duplicate of what you have tried but not showed

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z-GhkAEq5cDKGr-GU1HOMpytJN-KHptR/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fn08VIZWh8lLFH-wprCkyj4kz7px_0qd/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Please check above link

Comment: A photo of the code? Really? Please add the code as text here by editng question.

Comment: What happened when you tried ExifInterface?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to onActivityResult and pass Image path

```
public void rotateCapturedImage(String imagePath) {
        try {
            Bitmap sourceBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
            sourceBitmap = getScaledBitmap(sourceBitmap, MediaPickerActivity.this);
            ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(imagePath);
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
//          Toast.makeText(mContext,"orientation "+orientation,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            switch (orientation) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    bitmap = RotateBitmap(sourceBitmap, 90);
                    if (bitmap != null)
                        saveBitmap(bitmap, new File(imagePath));
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    bitmap = RotateBitmap(sourceBitmap, 180);
                    if (bitmap != null)
                        saveBitmap(bitmap, new File(imagePath));
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    bitmap = RotateBitmap(sourceBitmap, 270);
                    if (bitmap != null)
                        saveBitmap(bitmap, new File(imagePath));
                    break;

                default:
                    saveBitmap(sourceBitmap, new File(imagePath));
                    break;

            }
            sourceBitmap.recycle();
            if (bitmap != null)
                bitmap.recycle();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            // null value
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            // null value
        }
    }
```